# C# Strange Behaviour of Delegate Callbacks

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, callback

I wrote a class, that should provide basic interaction with NodeJS server. This class also includes TcpClient instance and works asynchronously (methods like BeginRead, BeginWrite, ...) so many functions takes callbacks (anonymous function using lambda expr.) as an argument. Problem starts in this scenario (I try to illustrate on a peace of code similar to original).

```
this._nodeJS.Send("DATA_TO_SEND", (Response) => {
    Console.WriteLine(Response);

    // Section1
    this._nodeJS.Send("ANOTHER_DATA", (Response1) => {
        Console.WriteLine(Response1);
    });
});
```

Problem occurs in **Section1**. When it's commented out, program behaves as expected. Response is received a written to Console. When it's not commented out, it starts to behave very strange. Write to Console in Section1 doesn't work (in many cases) and, what is important, code below Console.WriteLine in this section is not executed, the "thread" just stops right before command. I tried to debug it, step by step, variables in Section1 are correctly set, and when I get to the next command, debugging just stops. Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there some things I need to be aware of?

For better imagination here is my example. I connect to the NodeJS server, when it's done, I send a request and wait for response containing data, that are processed and again sent to the NodeJS server in next request (Section1). NodeJS give me final response and program works ... Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you perhaps disposing of the `_nodeJS` object after the send and before the callback, or assigning a new value to that variable?  Try creating a new nodeJS object inside of the first callback to use when sending the second `Send`, at least for diagnosing, if not in your final program.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. According to my original source, NodeJS instance is stored in Registry pattern, so there is only one instance of NodeJS. When I was debugging it and entered the section1, every single variable has the right value, every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out, what's goin' on. I know, I din't show my original code and instead used some kind of pseudo-code, but if someone is interested to know, problem, probably, was causing wrong conversion of received data. I have buffer of size 1024 and `StringBuilder` variable where the data was appended. So when I received the data, converted it this way: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer)` - this is wrong, instead, I had to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead)`. I don't know how, but this part of code was causing troubles and stopping callback to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your implementation details, I would suspect that the second `_nodeJS.Send(...` call is being blocked by the response from the first Send call.

At a guess, your code does something like this (made up pseudocode!):

```
void Send(String data, Action<Response> callback)
{
    _socket.BeginSend(Magic(data), r => {
        callback.Invoke(r.ResponseData);
        _socket.EndSend(r.Result);    //you cannot call _socket.Send() again until you have done this!
    });
}
```

Due to order of operations, it should be doing this:

```
void Send(String data, Action<Response> callback)
{
    _socket.BeginSend(Magic(data), r => {
        _socket.EndSend(r.Result);
        callback.Invoke(r.ResponseData);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the way I did it. In the send function i call EndWrite on the NetworkStream and then call my callback. Id like to highlight that second Send function is called after the response is successfuly received and all variables, including "Response1" variable contains correct data. Problem is, when I was finding the source of problem and debugging that code in section1, the "Thread" that was executing code Console.WriteLine(Response1) and the other ones, just stops. It seems like it was stopped by another Thread, its really strange for me.

Comment: @TomasPetovsky does it work if you take out just the `Console.Writeline();` calls? You could just increment an integer field to check its being called.

Comment: yeah, it works, I figured, that Console.WriteLine(); in many cases starts to work when I use Console.WriteLine(); in every callback function that is executed in current flow. But I really don't need to WriteLine anything, it's just for debugging purposes, what makes me sad if casct, that the code in section1 (in original version I have console.writeline and a lot of lines of code) simply just stops executing! It behaves, like it was stopped by by some other finished callback or something. I really dont know.